# creating summary of subset filtered dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying filtered data with value having 1 but the dataframe is already labelled . so the objective is to create a summary of filtered dataset

```
df <- data.frame(NY = c(1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1),
                 DE = c(2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1) )


df$NY<- factor(df$NY, levels =c(1,2), labels = c("unavailable","available"))
df$DE<- factor(df$DE, levels =c(1,2), labels = c("rejected","recieved"))
```

output is the frequency of "available" in both column
available/ total frequency in NY and DE for "recieved"

the output should be look like
[image]

Comment: I just updated question, because there can be another scenario

Comment: @AnilGoyal I think same number of frequencies in second col was making confusion now i have updated the question and i think the required output will get you all information about my requirement
28% is for  available only and 42% is for recieved  frequencies in columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If output in this format is useful?

```r
library(janitor)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  tabyl(name, value) %>%
  adorn_percentages() %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2)

#>  name available unavailable
#>    DE    50.00%      50.00%
#>    NY    71.43%      28.57%
```

---

In case of revised scenario

```
df %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  tabyl(value, name) %>%
  adorn_percentages('col') %>%
  filter(value %in% c('available', 'recieved')) %>%
  adorn_totals('row') %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2) %>%
  tail(1)

 value     DE     NY
 Total 50.00% 71.43%
```

Comment: if the DE column have "recieved","rejected" and i want to filtered recieved and summarise then...??

Comment: but the requirement is  the table should show percentage of frequency of "Available" for NY and "Recieved" for DE, so that going forward i can iterate for more dataframes

Comment: so like for NY  71% = no. freq of "available"/ total  and  for DE  50% = no. freq of "recieved"/ total , but the output show only , 50% and 71% like the output i showed for example

Comment: this is perfect as required

Comment: @str_rst, glad to help. Please accept and upvote as usually desired here

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse approach to your problem which outputs the percentages as decimal:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(. == "available")/n()))
```

Output:

```
         NY  DE
1 0.7142857 0.5
```

Comment: if the DE column have "recieved","rejected" and i want to filtered recieved and summarise then...??

Answer (score 0):

You can try `map_df()` through each column.

```
df %>% 
  map_df(
    ~ (mean(. == "available") * 100) %>% 
      round() %>% 
      paste("%")
  )

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#   NY    DE   
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 71 %  50 %
```

For different desired values, one approach is to create a named vector as below and pass it into a customised function. Note that the output is a character vector but you can change it as necessary.

```
values <- c(NY = "available",
            DE = "received")

get_percent <- function(.data, .values) {
  vars <- names(.values)
  pct <- sapply(
    seq_along(.values),
    function(.) round(mean(.data[[ vars[.] ]] == .values[vars[.]]) * 100)
  )
  pct <- paste0(pct, "%")
  names(pct) <- vars
  pct
}

res <- get_percent(df, values)
res

#    NY    DE 
# "29%" "43%"
```

Comment: if the DE column have "recieved","rejected" and i want to filtered recieved and summarise then...??

Comment: I added one approach for that to my answer. Hope this is helpful.